# Getting first row in Spring Data JPA

Tags: java, sql-server, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to implement a simple query that is logically equivalent to

```
select * from (
    select C.*, Row_number() OVER ( partition BY B.b_id ORDER BY C.c_id DESC ) as rn
    from C
    join B on B.b_id = C.b_id
    join A on A.a_id = B.a_id
    where A.other_field = 1234
) as subquery where rn = 1
```

In words: there are 1-N relations A -> B and B -> C; given an entity A, for each B get the last C. It should be possible to implement a native query, as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67172472/is-it-possible-to-use-window-functions-in-jpa), but I was hoping for a better approach. Is this the only way, as [this old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11206776/11478354) said?

Comment: Are you building an entity or java object from this data? Entities and rows have IDs/PKs to avoid using DB row num which can change, so I don't know why you'd be selecting it. Yes, you can build many native SQL functions into otherwise mostly JPQL query strings, but using a subquery result as the table to select from is JPA provider specific - so it depends on what you are using. If you are getting scalar results and just going to use it as such, and accessing DB specifics like row_num, using native SQL directly is the easiest option available.

Comment: @Chris yes, A, B and C are already entities. Row number is not a field entity. I'm selecting it only because "select ... where a_id = ... and row_number() over (...) = 1" is not a valid query. Another idea is to use a view in db to keep the code cleaner.

Comment: What about using the jooq? Create the navite query with jooq and pass the generated SQL to the entity manager.

Comment: @The5thcolumnmouse my desire is to use a simple query method, like the ones here https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I guess I found a solution for your problem, but without using window functions.

If I understand your question correctly, you want to retrieve the bigest C for each group of distinct B ***(1)*** - joining with A was done for filtering purposes.

This is the JPQL I wrote:

```sql
SELECT c FROM C c WHERE c.c_id IN (
  SELECT MAX(aux.c_id)
  FROM A a JOIN a.classesB b JOIN b.classesC aux
  WHERE a.other_field = 1234
  GROUP BY b.b_id)
```

And this is the code I wrote to verify the solution:

```java
@Entity(name = "A")
public class ClassA {

    @Id
    private long a_id;
    private long other_field;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "classA")
    private Set<ClassB> classesB;

    /* getters and setters omitted */
}

@Entity(name = "B")
public class ClassB {

    @Id
    private long b_id;
    @ManyToOne @JoinColumn(name = "a_id")
    private ClassA classA;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "classB")
    private Set<ClassC> classesC;

    /* getters and setters omitted */
}

@Entity(name = "C")
public class ClassC {

    @Id
    private long c_id;
    @ManyToOne @JoinColumn(name = "b_id")
    private ClassB classB;

    /* getters and setters omitted */
}

@Stateless
public class Service {

    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager em;

    public void execute() {
        em.createQuery("""
            SELECT c FROM C c WHERE c.c_id IN (
                SELECT MAX(aux.c_id)
                FROM A a JOIN a.classesB b JOIN b.classesC aux
                WHERE a.other_field = 1234
                GROUP BY b.b_id
            )
            """, ClassC.class)
            .getResultStream()
            .map(c -> "A: %05d B: %05d C: %05d".formatted(
                    c.getClassB().getClassA().getA_id(),
                    c.getClassB().getB_id(),
                    c.getC_id()))
            .forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

The `Service.execute()` method prints the result according to the understand described in **[1]**.

**Now, about the window functions.**

First of all, as per the [specification](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/persistence/3.1/jakarta-persistence-spec-3.1.html#a5196), you can't write subqueries into the `FROM` clause. So, even if window functions were accepted, it wouldn't be possible to use them in a subquery into the `FROM` clause - as you did in your example.

However, for the sake of understanding, let's try to execute just the inner query - without the `WHERE` clause of the outer query - and its window function:

```java
/* dummy object created to retrieve the result in a typed way */
public record QueryRecord(long c_id, long rn) {
}

@Stateless
public class Service {

    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager em;

    public void execute() {
        em.createQuery("""
            SELECT NEW package.QueryRecord(c.c_id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY b.b_id ORDER BY c.c_id DESC) AS rn)
            FROM C c JOIN c.classB b JOIN b.classA a
            WHERE a.other_field = 1234
            """, QueryRecord.class)
            .getResultStream()
            .forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

But, executing the previous code, gives the following exception:

```
org.hibernate.query.sqm.StrictJpaComplianceViolation: Encountered non-compliant non-standard function call [ROW_NUMBER], but strict JPA compliance was requested; use JPA's FUNCTION(functionName[,...]) syntax name instead
```

At this point, I was finding myself in a dead end. I could either insert `<property name="hibernate.jpa.compliance.query" value="false"/>` into the `persistence.xml` or use native queries. Both works fine, but I don't know if they would qualify as canonical answer.

Comment: You are right saying that the solution with the max subquery and with the rownumber subquery are logically equivalent (idk about performances). I will try to see if your solution is suitable, thank you.

Comment: You were right. The query I wrote for Spring JPA is even more simpler: 

"select c from CEntity c where c.id in (select max(c.id) from CEntity c where c.b.a.id = :aId group by c.bId)"

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this options

```
@Entity
@Immutable
@Subselect(
    "SELECT " +
    "    functions.*"
    "FROM (" +
    "    SELECT " +
    "        C.*, " +
    "        Row_number() OVER ( partition BY B.b_id ORDER BY C.c_id DESC ) as rn " +
    "    FROM " +
    "        C " +
    "     JOIN " +
    "         B " +
    "    ON " +
    "        B.b_id = C.b_id " +
    "     JOIN " +
    "         A " +
    "    ON " +
    "        A.a_id = B.a_id " +
    "    WHERE " +
    "        A.a_id = 1234 " +
    ") AS functions "
)
public class YourData {

    @Id
    private Integer propertieOfC1;

    private String propertieOfC2;

    // and more other for C table...

    private String propertieOfC3;

    private int rn;

    //getters and setters bellow
//hashcode and equals

}

@Repository
public interface YourDataRepository extends JpaRepository<YourData,Integer>{

    YourData findByRn(int rn);
}
```

or you can creat a viwer on database like this

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW your_functions_viwer AS
    SELECT
        functions.*
    FROM (
        SELECT
             C.*,
            Row_number() OVER ( partition BY B.b_id ORDER BY C.c_id DESC ) as rn
        FROM
            C
        JOIN
            B
        ON
             B.b_id = C.b_id
        JOIN
            A
        ON
              A.a_id = B.a_id
        WHERE
             A.a_id = 1234
    ) AS functions;
```

And then you can use on Java like this

```
@Entity
@Immutable
@Table(name = "your_functions_viwer")
public class YourData {

    @Id
    private Integer propertieOfC1;

    private String propertieOfC2;

    // and more other for C table...

    private String propertieOfC3;

    private int rn;

    //getters and setters bellow
//hashcode and equals


}



@Repository
public interface YourDataRepository extends JpaRepository<YourData,Integer>{

    YourData findByRn(int rn);
}
```

for more you can see the [vladmihalcea](https://vladmihalcea.com/map-jpa-entity-to-view-or-sql-query-with-hibernate/)

Comment: How is this different from a native query? Moreover, the entity already exists and this is not the only way to find it.

Comment: The difference is because on a native query e more like a select, and you only can do this select. When you use this soluction you are using an viwer like this [1] (https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sql-views/),   [2] (https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_view.asp),  [3] ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/views/views?view=sql-server-ver16) they are used for optimaze your consult, this represent like a new entity and you can do more consults in this select, change the attribute names, build other querys.

Comment: the first one is good but not better, the 2 is better because the responsability to create the viwer is in your database, and if you need change this is more easily to change on your database or if you need change the database is more easily.Native queries have a cost for update the database on project and its the only think (query) you can do.

Comment: I proposed the view solution myself in the comments... 

I was talking about the @Subselect annotation: moreover using a native query in the repository interface decouples the entity from the logic on how it is possible to find the object.